# Does the psychic abomination rule apply to an unmoving unit already within the effect radius?

Tags: warhammer-40k

The Culexus Assassin and Sisters of Silence's psychic abomination rule states that blessings and maledictions are nullified as soon as the target unit moves within 12" of the model. Does it means that one can still target a model that is already within 12" of a Sisters' unit or of an assassin with a malediction like treason of Tzeench and have it work as long as the target model doesn't move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Psychic Abomination basically creates a "null magic" zone where any psychic powers fail to manifest.

Comment: So say my friend has a farseer 20 inches away from my Culexus and I have a tactical squad 6 inches from my Culexus. The farseer gets to manifest his power because he is not inside the Psychic Abomination but he can't target my tactical squad because the marines are within it?

Comment: @Kenji - depending on the power type. Beam/Witchfire/Nova etc all work as normal, Blessings/Maledictions would cease to work once within 12". Technically, he can target them, but there just won't be any effect